# How to prevent previous fragment to show up after pressing back button using navigation controller?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use the navigation controller right now. I want to move from `LoginFragment` to `HomeFragment`. In `LoginFragment` I use this code below to move to `HomeFragment`.

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(homeDestination)
```

However, when I tap the back button in the `HomeFragment`, it will go back to `LoginFragment`, I expect that when I tap the button it will close the app.

In old way, if I use activity instead of using `Fragment`, I usually do something like this to get that expected behaviour:

```
val intent = Intent(this,HomeActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

By using those flags, I use to get the expected behavior. But I don't how to implement the same behavior using the navigation controller.

Comment: When you try to create new fragment from previous on, use replace in place of add. getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_between, policies, Policies.TAG)
                .addToBackStack(Policies.TAG).commit();

Comment: @Shane - you don't directly use FragmentTransactions when using [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation).

Comment: @Shane I am using android navigation component not using fragment transaction anymore https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing

Comment: Note that as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation#fixed) and the [conditional navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-conditional), you shouldn't be using a login fragment as your start destination.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Navigation offers a `popUpTo` and `popUpToInclusive` attributes for removing fragments from the back stack as part of a `navigate()` operation.

This can be set either in XML:

```
<!-- Add to your Navigation XML, then use navigate(R.id.go_home) -->
<action
  android:id="@+id/go_home"
  app:destination="@+id/home_fragment"
  app:popUpTo="@+id/destination_to_pop"
  app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

Or set it programmatically:

```
NavOptions navOptions = new NavOptions.Builder()
    .setPopUpTo(R.id.destination_to_pop, true)
    .build();
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(homeDestination, navOptions)
```

You can also use the id of a `<navigation>` element as well.

Answer (score 3):

I was following the answer of Ian but I had been having bad luck since I didn't know what the popUpTo would be.

So we have to use the id Of nav Graph there.

### `app:popUpTo="@+id/idOfNavGraph". //id of nav graph`

```
<action
  android:id="@+id/go_home"
  app:destination="@+id/home_fragment"
  app:popUpTo="@+id/idOfNavGraph". //id of nav graph
  app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

```
NavController controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
controller.popBackStack(R.id.fragmentLogin, true);
controller.navigate(homeDestination)
```

Comment: While this works in some way, Navigation offers a built in `popUpTo` attribute do this as a single operation, without sending updates to `OnDestinationChangedListener` for that intermediate state.

Comment: Ya. That's the right idea. I saw your answer later I posted mine. Your one is perfect. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 val c = view.findNavController()
 c.popBackStack() // current fragment will be pop up from the stack
 c.navigate(DestinationFragmentID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I'm late. Nonetheless I'd like to do my bit and expand Ian's answer. In `app:popUpTo="@+id/destination_to_pop"` the `destination_to_pop` really means the destination that you do not want to keep in the back stack. In your case, `loging_fragment`.

This way, when you navigate back from your `HomeFragment` the app will close since `LoginFragment` is not in the back stack anymore. You can find the related official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop).